# How do I find the xpath for a Floating Action Button in Android?

Tags: android, xpath, automation, appium, floating-action-button

So I am writing automation with appium and so far I've been using the appium inspector to gather my xpath data. I'm referencing everything via xpath due to my app not having unique identifiers on all elements.

On the main screen of my app there is a Floating Action Button, taken from the default Android code, that leads to a majority of the functionality of my app.

The Appium Inspector is not seeing the floating action button, just elements underneath it. Is there a special way for me to tell appium to click the FAB?

Thanks so much for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get past this issue by utilizing the Android Device Monitor to find the FAB.

The Android Device Monitor allowed me to view the FAB's unique resource-id "bottom_navigation_fab" when the Android Inspector would not even highlight the FAB.

I suppose the answer is to utilize both tools simultaneously and experiment a lot. Hope this helps someone else out there.